# Unable to set text of a draggable div on jquery full calendar (asp.net mvc5 application)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I am following this article to create draggable items and drop it on jquery full calendar.
http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.1/demos/external-dragging.html

I have a draggable div originally whose text is "Select to Create Call"
I had to customize it to create titles by selecting what user selects in two dropdowns and then forming a title out of it.
It definitely shows the title on the div, but when I drag and drop it it shows the original text i.e. Select to Create Call
I am assuming the reason is that it drops a clone on the jquery full calendar.
Please find below the code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var calendar = $('#calendar');
        // eventSources: [getCalData()],
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            // calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month'
            }, editable: true, droppable: true,
            // eventSources: [
            //   {
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")',
                    // dataType: 'json',
                    data: {

                        month: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month(),
                        year: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').year()
                    },
                    success: function (doc) {

                        var events = [];
                        $.each(doc, function (index, event) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                        });

                    }
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ChangeEvents", "Calendar")',

                    data: {
                        eventsJson: JSON.stringify(event)

                    }

                });


            },

            drop: function(event,allDay) {
                //drop functionality goes here
              /*  var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');

                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                copiedEventObject.start = event.date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);*/

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddEvents", "Calendar")',

                    data: {
                        eventsJson: JSON.stringify(event),
                        //datePicked: date,
                        title: $('#total-title').text(),
                        ddlAttending: $('#ddlAttending').val(),
                        ddlCallType: $('#ddlCallType').val()
                    },

                   /* success: function (data) {
                        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

                            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                            $(this).data('event', {
                                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                            });

                            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                            $(this).draggable({
                                zIndex: 999,
                                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                            });

                        });

                    }*/


                });

                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            } 

        });

        function saveEvent(event, dayDelta) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeEvents", "Calendar")',
                data: {

                    id: event.id,
                    daysMoved: dayDelta
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
        }



        $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
            var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
            //alert('next is clicked, do something');
            events: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")'
        });

        $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
            //alert('prev is clicked, do something');
             events:'@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")'
        });




       $.ajax({


            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                  $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {


                    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title:  $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });

                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });

                });

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                debugger;
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });

    });


        function createNewEvent()
        {
            // $("#drop2").val( $("#drop").val() + ' ' + $("#drop1").val());
            $('#total-title').text($("#ddlAttending :selected").text() + ' ' + $("#ddlCallType :selected").text());
            //alert($('#total-title').text())
           // $('#total-title').text($("#drop2").val());
        }


</script>
```

The body contains the following divs:

```
 <div>
                <div id="calendar" style="width:85%"></div>
                <div id='external-events' style="width:15%;margin-top:40px;margin-left:13px">

                    <h4>
                        Create Draggable Events
                    </h4>

                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlAttending", (SelectList)ViewBag.PersonelID, "-Select Attending-", new { @style = "margin:5px;" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCallType", (SelectList)ViewBag.OnCallType, "-Select CallType-", new { @style = "margin:5px;", onchange = "createNewEvent();" })

                    <span class='fc-event' contenteditable="true" id="total-title" style="width: 155px; margin: 5px;">Select to create call</span>



                </div>


            </div>
```

I am using asp.net mvc5 framework to fetch events and save events on the page.
As the picture shows that the div has the updated text after selecting from drodpowns but dragging onto calendar still shows "Select to Create Call"

[image]

Comment: in your code you have a comment section saying `// store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop` there you are saving the data with the initial text. I think you need to make changes here

Comment: In this section, it always picks up the first text. I am not sure how to incorporate this ajax function in drop method to store updated value.
$(this).data('event', {
                        title:  $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });

Comment: I found the answer: Put this functionality in the drop function and comment it on document.resdy.onload

 $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title: $('#total-title').text(), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });
                });

Comment: You can add it as answer, it might help others with similar issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

Put this functionality in the drop function and comment it on document.ready.onload

```
$('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () 
   { $(this).data('event', 
      { title: $('#total-title').text(), // use the element's text as the title                        
        stick: true // maintain when user navigates 
   }); 
  });
```

So the final script looks like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        var calendar = $('#calendar');


        // eventSources: [getCalData()],
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            // calendar.fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month'
            }, editable: true, droppable: true,
            // eventSources: [
            //   {
            events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")',
                    // dataType: 'json',
                    data: {

                        month: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').month(),
                        year: $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate').year()
                    },
                    success: function (doc) {

                        var events = [];
                        $.each(doc, function (index, event) {
                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event);
                        });

                    }
                });
            },
            eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc) {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ChangeEvents", "Calendar")',

                    data: {
                        eventsJson: JSON.stringify(event)

                    }

                });


            },

            drop: function (event, allDay) {
                alert($('#total-title').text());
                //drop functionality goes here
                $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title: $('#total-title').text(), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AddEvents", "Calendar")',

                    data: {
                        eventsJson: JSON.stringify(event),
                        //datePicked: date,
                        title: $('#total-title').text(),
                        ddlAttending: $('#ddlAttending').val(),
                        ddlCallType: $('#ddlCallType').val()
                    },

                    /*success: function (data) {
                        callback(data);
                        // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert(data.title);
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', event, true);
                        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

                            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                            $(this).data('event', {
                                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                            });

                            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                            $(this).draggable({
                                zIndex: 999,
                                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                            });

                        });

                        }*/


                    });

                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            } 

        });

        function saveEvent(event, dayDelta) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("ChangeEvents", "Calendar")',
                data: {

                    id: event.id,
                    daysMoved: dayDelta
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
        }



        $('.fc-next-button').click(function () {
            var date = $("#calendar").fullCalendar('getDate');
            //alert('next is clicked, do something');
            events: '@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")'
        });

        $('.fc-prev-button').click(function () {
            //alert('prev is clicked, do something');
             events:'@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Calendar")'
        });
 $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

                // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
              /*  $(this).data('event', {
                    title: $(this).find("p").html($("#ddlAttending :selected").text() + ' ' + $("#ddlCallType :selected").text()),//$.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                });*/

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                });
            });
  });
    function createNewEvent()
        {
            // $("#drop2").val( $("#drop").val() + ' ' + $("#drop1").val());
            $('#total-title').text($("#ddlAttending :selected").text() + ' ' + $("#ddlCallType :selected").text());
            //alert($('#total-title').text())
           // $('#total-title').text($("#drop2").val());
        } 
    </script>

<div>
                <div id="calendar" style="width:85%"></div>
                <div id='external-events' style="width:15%;margin-top:40px;margin-left:13px">

                    <h4>
                        Create Draggable Events
                    </h4>

                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlAttending", (SelectList)ViewBag.PersonelID, "-Select Attending-", new { @style = "margin:5px;" })
                    @Html.DropDownList("ddlCallType", (SelectList)ViewBag.OnCallType, "-Select CallType-", new { @style = "margin:5px;", onchange = "createNewEvent();" })

                    <div class='fc-event' contenteditable="true" id="total-title" style="width: 155px; margin: 5px;" data-title="ok"><p>Select to create call</p></div>



                </div>


            </div>
```